# Take a summary of cell values from the last 5 days of workbooks into single workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a requirement that once a week on a Friday I need to pull some data from workbooks generated each day of the week (Mon-Fri) into a weekly dated summary in a new workbook. The new workbook is to be a cumulative view of each week with the date auto populated on the Friday when the data is pasted into the summary sheet.

I need some pointers on how to logically work out the current date, search back to find the first file from that Monday (but include Friday's file) and then to insert the range of dates from that week into the corresponding cells next to the copied data.

I've found various posts from others looking to do a similar thing, and I've attempted to begin working on that basis to produce what I want it to do. However, I'm not trained in VBA so I am attempting everything on a 'best efforts' basis. The below is the code I have written which currently just opens up the last file in the directory. I also have a separate tab with the public holidays I want it to take into account when running the macro. Clearly there's a lot for me to do, I would be grateful for any tips and pointers on what I should try.

```
Sub WeeklyUpdate()

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
Dim LastPreviousWorkday As Date

'date format to use and where to lookup the bank holidays
LastPreviousWorkday = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, -1)
LastPreviousWorkday = Format$(LastPreviousWorkday, ("yyyy-mm-dd"))
LastPreviousWorkday = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, -1, Worksheets("PublicHolidays").Range("A:A"))

'This is where I want it to opens the last 5 days of workbooks from today's date including today e.g. Monday-Friday, report is always run on a Friday
Workbooks.Open "W:\Inventory\Inventory Support\3. Reporting\Daily\Daily Fails Report\Daily Fails Report " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsb"

  'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
  Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Daily Fails Report 2019-06-26.xlsb").Worksheets("Daily Fails Report (National)")
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("Weekly Issues Summary.xlsb").Worksheets("CurrentPeriodSummary")

'Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column O
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row

'Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column B
'Offset property moves down 1 row to exclude headers
 lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row


'Copy data range excluding the grand total which is always the last row (so use -1 to select the last row above it) & Paste Data into Summary
  wsCopy.Range("O9:Q" & lCopyLastRow - 1).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow)


End Sub
```

I expect the output of the above to update my summary workbook with five lines of data per week with a date against each one that corresponds to the date in the name of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I need some pointers on how to logically work out the current date, search back to find the first file from that Monday (but include Friday's file) and then to insert the range of dates from that week into the corresponding cells next to the copied data.*

The following function outputs the date range (as an array), from `Today` going back to the previous Monday.

```
Option Explicit
Function dateStuff() As Date()
    Dim lastMonday As Date
    Dim arrDates() As Date
    Dim I As Long

lastMonday = Date - Weekday(Date, vbMonday) + 1

ReDim arrDates(0 To Date - lastMonday)
For I = 0 To UBound(arrDates)
    arrDates(I) = lastMonday + I
Next I

dateStuff = arrDates

End Function
```

You can then use the output of this function to create the names for the corresponding workbooks.

If I understand what you are doing correctly, there shouldn't be a need to exclude holidays from this list.  Since you won't have a workbook generated for a holiday, just test to see if the workbook exists when you are trying to obtain the data.

Here's a routine to put the generated date range into some cell.  You can work out how to change `rOutput` to reflect your real target cell.  This `Sub` depends on the above `Function`:

```
Sub insertDateRange()
    Dim dateRange() As Date
    Dim rOutput As Range

Set rOutput = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B1")

dateRange = dateStuff

rOutput = dateRange(0) & " - " & dateRange(UBound(dateRange))

End Sub
```

Run Today `27-Jun-2019` the macro will output `6/24/2019 - 6/27/2019`

but you can use the VBA Format function to change the output format of the dates if you desire.

**EDIT:**

So far as opening the workbooks and processing them, it's just a matter of iterating through the output of the `dateStuff` function to generate your workbook paths.  eg:

```
'This is where I want it to opens the last 5 days of workbooks from today's date including today e.g. Monday-Friday, report is always run on a Friday
Dim wbDates() As Date, Idx As Long
Dim wbDaily As Workbook, wbPath As String
wbDates = dateStuff 'wbDates now contains an array of the relevant dates

'This will open the workbooks one at a time and you can process them as you wish
'You should refer to this daily workbook as `wbDaily` or some other variable of your choice
For Idx = LBound(wbDates) To UBound(wbDates)
    wbPath = "W:\Inventory\Inventory Support\3. Reporting\Daily\Daily Fails Report\Daily Fails Report " & Format(wbDates(Idx), "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsb"
    If Len(Dir(wbPath)) > 0 Then  'workbook exists
        Set wbDaily = Workbooks.Open(wbPath)
         'your code
         '.....
         wbDaily.Close
    End If
Next Idx
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips, those are helpful and solves the issue with needing to place the date range in the new workbook.  However, I don't need to generate the names for the workbooks containing the data, they will already be in place at the end of the week in the required location. I'm really looking for a way to get those 5 files open without having to explicitly hard code the filenames, I want it to understand to look for the current day and last 4 working days formatted as: Daily Fails Report " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsb". Does that make sense?

Comment: @Clare Seems you're already doing that (for `Today`) with your `Workbooks.Open "W:\Inventory\Inventory Support\3. Reporting\Daily\Daily Fails Report\Daily Fails Report " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsb"` statement.  It's just a matter of iterating through the output of my `dateStuff` function to generate the file names.  I'll add some code to my answer.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I'm quite new to all this so I didn't understand the first time. I've amended my code now and it's working correctly to copy across the comments. I'm just fine tuning the inserting the date as that part works as per your example but I want to insert each date from the range into individual cells so I will work that part out and share my code on here for anyone who might be interested. Thanks for your help